# No service for type Identity.RoleManager - Identity.IdentityRole has been registered error

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, service-provider

I use Microsoft Identity for the first time. I configured users and roles with IdentityUser and IdentityRole. I want to assign a role to users in Startup.cs. I wrote a method to make it which is

```
private async Task CreateUserRoles(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {


      var roleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole<int>>>();
      var userManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<User>>();

      var roleName = "Super Admin";
      var roleCheck = await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName);
      if (!roleCheck) {
            Role role = new Role();
            role.Name = roleName;
            IdentityResult result = roleManager.CreateAsync(role).Result;
            //IdentityResult roleResult = await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole<int>(roleName));
      }
      User user = new User();
      user.UserName = "someone";
      user.Password = "someone";
      user.Email = "someone@gmail.com";
      ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
      context.Users.Add(user);
      context.SaveChanges();
      user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync("someone@gmail.com");

      await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, roleName);
}
```

Hovewer there is a problem :

```
No service for type 
'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole1[System.Int32]]' has been registered.
```

How can I fix it?

Here is a Startup.cs

```
  public class Startup {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) {
              Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
              services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options => {
                    // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
              });

              services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
              services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();


              // Add MVC services to the services container.
              services.AddMvc();
              services.AddDistributedMemoryCache(); // Adds a default in-memory implementation of IDistributedCache
              services.AddSession(opt => { opt.Cookie.IsEssential = true; });

              services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
                          .AddRazorPagesOptions(options => {
                                options.AllowAreas = true;
                                options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Identity", "/Account/Settings");
                                options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaPage("Identity", "/Account/Logout");
                          });
              services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                                options.UseNpgsql("User ID = postgres; Password = sa; Host = localhost; Port = 5432; Database = CCN; Pooling = true;"));

              services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
                    options.LoginPath = $"/Account/Login"; //options.LoginPath = $"/Identity/Account/Login";
                    options.LogoutPath = $"/Account/Logout";
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = $"/Account/AccessDenied";
              });



              //Password settings
              services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(o => {
                    o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                    o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                    o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                    o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                    //o.Password.RequiredLength = 3;

              }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
              .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider services) {

              app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
              app.UseStatusCodePages();
              if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
                    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
              }
              else {
                    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Index");
                    app.UseHsts();
              }

              app.UseHttpsRedirection();
              app.UseStaticFiles();
              app.UseCookiePolicy();
              //Enable session 
              app.UseSession();


              app.UseAuthentication();

              app.UseMvc(routes => {
                    routes.MapRoute(
                        name: "default",
                        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
              });

              //Create user role and assign it  
              CreateUserRoles(services).Wait();

        }

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried those solutions but it didn't work. Then I recognize that I created an entity called Role which is derived from IdentityRole and its id data type is int. I changed

```
var roleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole<int>>>();
```

this line with

```
var roleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<Role>>();
```

this one. Then it works. 
On the other hand, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

> No service for type 
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole1[System.Int32]]' has been registered.

When registering `IdentityRole` for the AspNetCore Identity, the RoleManager<> type will be registered to the ServiceCollection as `RoleManager<IdentityRole>`.

**Whenever you want to resolve the `RoleManager<>`, specify the identity role model registered in your startup as the type parameter.** Which would be `RoleManager<IdentityRole>` in your specific case.

When calling `GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()` on the resulting service provider, `GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()` will throw the above exception.

Make the below modification:

**In CreateUserRoles**

```
var roleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
```

**Register the role services in the DI container （choose one of the two methods）**

1.Use AddIdentity()

```
services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole()
        .AddDefaultUI()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

2.Use AddDefaultIdentity , include roles by using the `[AddRoles][1]` method

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<User>()
        .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Reference : [AddDefaultIdentity and AddIdentity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#adddefaultidentity-and-addidentity)

Answer (score -1):

When adding services to Startup, in this part here:

```
//Password settings
              services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(o => {
                    o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                    o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                    o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                    o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                    //o.Password.RequiredLength = 3;

              }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
              .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

You could put it like this:

```
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddRoles<IdentityRole<int>>()
                  .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

With the `IdentityRole<int>`

I believe that's why it wasn't recognizing the service being registered.

Comment: Please translate your explanation to english, as this is the main language on StackOverflow